# SwiftUI NavigationLink Bug (SwiftUI encountered an issue when pushing aNavigationLink. Please file a bug.)

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

**Console Bug:** *SwiftUI encountered an issue when pushing aNavigationLink. Please file a bug.*

There is no problem when I don't use the isActive parameter in NavigationLink. However, I have to use the isActive parameter. Because I'm closing the drop-down list accordingly.

**Menu Model:**

```
struct Menu: Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var pageName: String
    var icon: String
    var page: Any
    var startDelay: Double
    var endDelay: Double
//    var offsetY: CGFloat
}

let menu = [
    Menu(id: 1, pageName: "Profil", icon: "person.crop.circle", page: ProfileView(), startDelay: 0.2, endDelay: 0.6),
    Menu(id: 2, pageName: "Sepet", icon: "cart", page: CartView(), startDelay: 0.4, endDelay: 0.4),
    Menu(id: 3, pageName: "İstek", icon: "plus.circle", page: ClaimView(), startDelay: 0.6, endDelay: 0.2)
]
```

**MenuView**

```
struct MenuView: View {
    @State var isShownMenu: Bool = false
    @State var isPresented: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 40) {
            
            Button(action: {self.isShownMenu.toggle()}) {
                MenuViewButton(page: .constant((Any).self), icon: .constant("rectangle.stack"))
            }
            VStack(spacing: 40) {
                ForEach(menu, id: \.id) { item in
                    
                    NavigationLink(
                        destination: AnyView(_fromValue: item.page),
                        isActive: self.$isPresented,
                        label: {

                            MenuViewButton(page: .constant(item.page), icon: .constant(item.icon))
                        .animation(Animation.easeInOut.delay(self.isShownMenu ? item.startDelay : item.endDelay))
                        .offset(x: self.isShownMenu ? .zero : UIScreen.main.bounds.width)//, y: item.offsetY)
                }
            }
            .onChange(of: isPresented, perform: { value in
                if value == true {
                    self.isShownMenu = false
                }
            })
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have 3 (count of menu items) NavigationLink/s linked to 1 isPresented state property. Which one do you think should be activated? ... this is a bug of code logic.

Comment: Also, Navigation in SwiftUI sucks. Anything this easy to break is just bad design. :( Avoid the use of the binder when at all possible, and dismiss via presentation mode in the destination.

Comment: there is one solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/69484580/7576100

Comment: For me this happened when I had the same Bool binding in two different `NavigationLinks`

Comment: I'm having the same problem now, but am only using `NavigationLink` without the `isActive` parameter. What else could be the problem?

Answer (score 38):

The problem is that you have NavigationLink with the "IsActive" parameter placed in the ForEach cycle!
You need to remove NavigationLink from the cycle and transfer the necessary data there, for example, through the view model.

Summary: you should only have one NavigationLink associated with one specific isActive parameter.

```
 ForEach(yourData) { dataItem in
     Button {
         selectedItem = dataItem
         isActivated = true
     } label: {
         Text("\(dataItem)")            
     }
 }
 .background(
     NavigationLink(destination: DestinationView(data: selectedItem),
                    isActive: $isActivated) {EmptyView()}
 )
```

Comment: this is working for me but how are you gonna handle for example contente download in DestinationView? onAppear is being called just once, not everytime a DestinationView is pushed

Comment: The data can be processed in the variable's setter 'selectedItem'.

Answer (score 2):

I got this when I accidentally had two NavigationLinks with the same isActive boolean.

Comment: this was it! thank you :) quicker than chatgpt ❣️

Answer (score 0):

```
ForEach(items) { item in
            NavigationLink(tag: item.id, selection: $selection) {
                DetailView(selection: $selection, item: item)
            } label: {
                Text("\(item)")
            }
        }
```